# Representation and naming of coordinates in n-dimensional space

Tags: java, naming-conventions, representation, data-representation

Currently I am making a Breakout game, and I thought about the representation of coordinates as well as the naming convention for them. In this particular example you only have two coordinates x and y in a 2-dimensional space.

[image]

Is the best representation for (even 2-dimensional) coordinates-systems: arrays? Why would it still be useful to use `int` in these kind of situations? When does it make sense to switch to an array? It seems bad practise that when you use variables just as a way to describe the order in which they appear like you do with x and y in a coordinate system.

Which will be more efficient? Will working with a 2-dimensional array be faster than working with two basic integers? Will updating a value be faster as an integer or array? I assume that working with arrays with more dimensions be far easier to manipulate.

```
int[] coordinates = {1,2}; //initializing, which way is faster? 
int xPosition = 1;
int yPosition = 2;

xPosition = 2; //updating the coordinates, which way is faster?
yPosition = 3;
coordinates = {2, 3};
```

To end this madness: What would be the best variable names if you were to choose `int`s? These are my struggles:

```
int xPosition, yPosition //a bit long
int xPos, yPos //looks short and clear to me, but maybe there is an 
//'normal' way to do it?
int xpos, ypos //short and looks less clear but represents better imo
// that it's one entity
int positionX, positionY //auto-complete takes twice as long
int posY, posX //harder to see what's meant here for me
```

Answer (score 2):

n-dim. Arrays as a low level structure are good enough and an optimal choice for your case:

- Those coordinates are static in size.
- You easily access the elements by their index.
- Iterating is much faster and easy to read.
- No search or sort algortihms needed.

Just make sure you initially define the exact size to avoid castings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: And i would tend to use either positionX or posX, because camelCase, but you should stay at one convention to keep an overall persistent code apperance.

Comment: i use posX too but would like to know what's the majority